# Accuracy in DNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

How does number of batch size and steps per epoch affects the accuracy of the model? Edit: Training and validation accuracy both.

I trained a model using CNN where the accuracy is changing relatively to the step per epochs.

Comment: Training, or Validation/Test Accurcay?

If you increase the batch size you should also increase the learning rate! 
If you did that then:
Using a smaller BatchSize can have an regularizing effect on the model, thus is should overfit less to the training set and the performance on validation sets can improve.

Comment: I edited now. Actually training and validation accuracy.   So you're saying that smaller batch size would give better accuracy than larger batch size.

Comment: Its not a law, but this trend can be observed for many models